# Postgresql: pivoting a column without crosstab

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

i've tried to pivot a column in a concatenation of string i see is possible with crosstab but i can't install tablefunc.
i've a list of tables and columns name
what obtain from the following query

```
SELECT 
 table_name
, column_name
FROM 
   information_schema.columns


 table_name| column_name
     tab_1 |id
      tab_1|email
      tab_2|field_1
       tab2|field_2
```

What i want obtain is :

```
 table_name| column_name
      tab_1|id, email
      tab_2|field_1, field_2
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want string aggregation:

```
select table_name, string_agg(column_name, ', ') column_name
from information_schema.columns
group by table_name
```

Comment: Query is working fine. But it is showing ```postgres```'s default tables as well. How to exclude them?

Comment: it  works correctly, and i add at the  string_agg the order by function for a correct concatenation order using a field in the information_schema tab.